# C# Error: The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, point

Whats the best way to make "Point" public? i can't figure out how to do this.
Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Car
{
    public class Car : Form
    {
       public Car(Form1 form1)
       {
           form1.Car.Location = new Point(form1.x, form1.y);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "are you missing a using directive?"  Yes.  Please read the error message before you ask for help.

Comment: Given answer clearly explains that you are missing `using System.Drawing;` but `form1.Car.Location` seems odd when you have `class Car` and also namespace `Car`.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a problem with `Point` being public.  The problem is that you haven't told the compiler where to find that type, hence the "could not be found" message.

You can either change `Point` to `System.Drawing.Point` or add this line to the top:

```
using System.Drawing;
```